# How to open new page on same page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have aspx page popup in my project.

I want to open page in a same window, for example when you search on Google several link appear and click on any link that link open in same tab.

I want this in asp.net

Comment: u can use user controls

Comment: which user control ????

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1739/User-controls-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 2):

Thats not related to ASP.NET but javascript. Use [`window.open`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp):

```
window.open("", "_self");
```

Comment: this method open in popup window not a current tab

Comment: `_self` should open it in the current tab, but maybe this is controlled by the user's browser preferences and it can't be overridden.